# My laptop drains battery even it is shut down

Tags: battery, hp-envy

Even I shutdown my laptop , the battery drains . If I plug a mouse or keyboard , LED indicator on keyboard turns on , and the mouse also got power ,even the laptop is completely off , and power cable is unplugged . How can I fix this ?

My laptop model is : [HP ENVY 15-k020us](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04326327)

Comment: This is a not uncommon feature, to allow charging when shut down. There may be control over powered ports and interfaces in the BIOS. Otherwise, all you can do is unplug everything.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like your computer is just hibernating or sleeping rather than completely off.

Comment: How are you shutting down the computer to an 'off' state? Just pressing the power button generally puts it in a hibernate mode (windows).

Comment: I just shut down , no hibernation or sleep

Answer (score -1):

These laptops are generally known to not shut down properly.  I have spent over 2 years trying to get mine to shut down completely, but it stays on.  Make sure this isn't happening to you by checking to make sure all the power lights are off after the screen turns off.

There are a number of "fixes" out there for this issue, but they don't seem to work for many people.  Just make sure you hold the power button down until it turns off completely (after it finishes the shutdown process) if it doesn't completely power off on its own.

Comment: Wow, you spent two years trying to turn off your laptop?

Comment: So, are you offering the last sentence of your post ("... make sure you hold the power button down until it turns off completely ...") as your answer? You could improve this post by focusing on the solution and cutting back on the fluff.

Comment: Scott, in this case, some background information is needed as this offers a temporary fix, not a permanent solution.